# Regex - get only string after numbers and before parenthesis (ex. 1. Manhattan (NY))

Tags: python, regex

New to regex,
what I have so far is `'([A-Za-z]^[^\(]+)'`
but I am getting "list index out of range" error.

I want to get only "Manhattan" out of "1. Manhattan (NY)"

Comment: To get it in the first capture group: `\d+\.\s+(\w+)\s+\(`

Comment: You used `^` in the middle, it makes it invalid as `^` matches start of string. Replace `^` with `+`, `[A-Za-z][^(]+`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/9igJkv/1) (with `re.search`)

Comment: Stephan Schlecht already answered. Just as a future reference, I always find https://regex101.com/ a great tool for creating and testing regex.

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like this:

```
import re

txt = "(ex. 1. Manhattan (NY))"
m = re.search(r'[0-9]+\.\s+([^(]+)', txt)
if m:
    print(m.group(1))
```

This would print out:

```
Manhattan
```

Answer (score 0):

The caret (^) has two main purposes. One, ^ is used to indicate the start of the string, and as such, is normally at the start of your regular expression. The second is within square brackets ([]). If the caret is the first character within the square brackets, then it acts as a "not" (match everything other than the characters listed in the square brackets).

I think that error may be coming from the caret (^) that you have in the "middle" of your regex; the first caret in your expression.

That still will not get your correct answer, but it should fix that problem.

'([A-Za-z]+)\s('  -- Should find and capture all contiguous alpha characters followed by 0-n whitespace characters followed by a left parenthesis. You have to decide if you want to include spaces in the captured value. And, are all values followed by a left parenthesis?

You can use https://pythex.org/ (or similar tools) to test your regular expression.

Answer (score 0):

If your data has a regular structure, such as something, spaces, necessary data, spaces and something else, then it is easier to use the [`split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) method:

```
txt = '1. Manhattan (NY)'
chunks = txt.split(maxsplit=3)
if len(chunks) > 1:
    print(chunks[1])
```

[Demo](https://rextester.com/PECL82575).

In Python 2, a call to the [`split`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) method is converted to: `chunks = txt.split(None, 3)`.

[Demo](https://rextester.com/OVUFOH35394).